# Sending e-mail using VB on ASP.NET through Gmail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gmail

I am trying to send an email from an ASP page using gmail, but when I try to send it, i just get "Error sending mail", with no description other than that.
SMTP is enabled on the gmail box I'm using and also working from mobile devices.
If anyone could give me a hand with this, I'll appreciate it.

Thanks.-

```
    Friend Shared Sub Send_Mail(Destinatario As String)

        Dim Message As New MailMessage()


        Dim SmtpC = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")

        Message.From = New MailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com")
        Message.To.Add(Destinatario)

        Message.Subject = "Some Subject"
        Message.Body = "Message body"

        SmtpC.Port = 465
        SmtpC.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "somepassword")
        SmtpC.EnableSsl = True





        Try
            SmtpC.Send(Message)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please make sure port 587 is not being blocked.

Comment: Also potentially answered before stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: Hi Martin this [URL](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vbnet.aspx?cat=2) should be helping you to deal with you problem, if not please let me know

Comment: Port 587 isn't being blocked, as i can connect to gmail using Telnet.

Comment: After reading the links provided by willie and xmorera, i rewrote the function based on it (posted the new version on the main question), but still the error persists. I am at a loss regarding the issue.

Comment: Check your anti-virus software. McAfee for instance blocks your own mail scripts as "spam mailworm"